# How can I remove my Stack Overflow account? I made a mistake

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

I absently made a Stack Overflow account and I don't want it. How do I delete it?

Please help. I am getting spammed with email. My "special" email is only for "special" things ;), not anything else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: You know you can unsubscribe, right? You don't need to delete your account with a service to stop receiving email, and there's no guarantee that deleting an account actually will stop the email. (For shadier services, there's no guarantee that unsubscribing will stop the email either, but deleting your account doesn't actually express an intent that you want to stop getting email.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to your user profile by clicking your profile picture on the top right, click on profile next to activity, then once you see your profile picture you should see an 'edit profile link, on the left navigation bar about midways down there is a delete profile option!